# Evaluate $\int\frac1{1+x^n}dx$ for $n\in\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, indefinite-integrals

I was wondering on how to evaluate the following indefinite integral for all $n\in\mathbb R$.

$$\int\frac1{1+x^n}dx$$

It seems to be peculiar in that we have

$$\begin{align}
\int\frac1{1+x^{-1}}dx&=x-\ln(x+1)+c\\
\int\frac1{1+x^0}dx&=\frac12x+c\\
\int\frac1{1+x^{1/2}}dx&=2\sqrt x-2\ln(1+\sqrt x)+c\\
\int\frac1{1+x^1}dx&=\ln(x+1)+c\\
\int\frac1{1+x^2}dx&=\arctan(x)+c\\
\int\frac1{1+x^3}dx&=\frac13\ln(1+x)-\frac2{3\sqrt3}\arctan\left(\sqrt{\frac43}\left(x-\frac12\right)\right)+c
\end{align}$$

Naturally, there appears to be some combination of $\ln$ and $\arctan$, though no simple formula arises to solve the general case.

It is, however, easy to see that

$$\int\frac1{1+x^{-n}}dx=\int1-\frac1{1+x^n}dx$$

So there is an easy enough connection between positive and negative $n$.

Also, it is easy enough to find the series expansion, taking advantage of the above connection we just made to circumvent problems concerning convergence.

$$\frac1{1+x^n}=1-x^n+x^{2n}-x^{3n}+\dots\forall\ |x|<1$$

$$\int\frac1{1+x^n}dx=c+x-\frac1{n+1}x^{n+1}+\frac1{2n+1}x^{2n+1}-\dots$$

$$=c+\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{kn+1}x^{kn+1}\ \forall\ |x|<1$$

Though this isn't very much along the lines of closed form.

For $n=\frac ab$, where $a$ and $b$ are whole numbers, we can use the substitution $x=u^b$ to get

$$\int\frac1{1+x^n}dx=\int\frac{bu^{b-1}}{1+u^a}du$$

<s>though I'm unsure where that could lead.</s>  This reduces the integral down to

$$\int\frac1{1+x^n}dx=b\int P(u)+\frac{u^{b-1-ak}}{1+u^a}du,\quad k\in\mathbb N$$

for some polynomial $P(u)$.  Though I'm still clueless as to how this can be advanced.

> How can I evaluate $\int\frac1{1+x^n}dx\ \forall\ n\in\mathbb R$ in closed form?  Can someone prove there at least exists some closed form solution for all $n\in\mathbb Q$ if the above is not possible?  If possible, use real numbers.

Comment: I'm curious about whether anything can be done with $\frac 1{1+x^{-n}}+\frac 1{1+x^n}=1$, this seems to be a relatively powerful identity that I hadn't considered before...

Comment: One way to connect all of these integrals is with the [hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function).  In particular, [one may compute](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+1%2F(1+%2B+x%5En)+dx) that
$$
\int \frac{1}{1 + x^n}\,dx = x \cdot {}_2F_1(1,1/n;1 + 1/n; -x^n) + C
$$
However, since the hypergeometric function is defined in terms of its power series, this is not a terribly satisfying epiphany.

Comment: I have a 150 page table of mathematical formulas in my bookshelf where 20 of those are devoted to indeterminate integrals. It lists this integral for $n = 1, 2, 3$ and $4$ separately, and that's it for your integrals (although the integrals for $1/(1-x^n)$ are also listed for the same $n$). I think that would suggest that no nice closed form was known at the time of printing, which was 2003.

Comment: I was looking at the same problem a while ago and posted a solution. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1837784/help-verifying-equation-int-0-x-frac11tn-dt

Comment: @926reals That is quite nice.  I too have spotted that solution, however, it is problematic that it doesn't really qualify as a closed form solution.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom See [THIS ANSWER](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1354106/what-is-the-integration-of-int-1-x2n-1dx/1354485#1354485) in which I developed a closed-form solution. ;-))

Comment: @926reals The below answer is quite spectacular.

Comment: @Simple art: It requires calculation of, cos(?), sin(?), Atan(??), and log (???), and knowing the value of PI.  How do we do that.  That was my quest, how to skip all of it.

Comment: @926reals IMO, it is easier than an infinite sum.  Also thought you would like it.

Comment: @simple art, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2018468/solving-the-integral-int-fracx-alpha1-psi-x-mathrm-dx/2020799#2020799.

Comment: These two questions are also related (by not the same, since they do not request solution as combination of arctan and log): 
[Solving this integral $\int\frac{1}{1+x^n} dx$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/777263) and
[How to find the indefinite integral $\int \frac{dx}{1+x^{n}}$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/742173)

Comment: Also related (I only stumbled upon this question now): https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2807302/96384

Comment: It is possible to simplify the hypergeometric function to an [incomplete beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function), see [Calculating integrals of the form $\int\frac{dx}{(1+x^{q})^\frac{p}{r}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4333041/323432). One then gets
$$\int \frac{dx}{1+x^n}=\frac{1}{n}B\left(\frac{x^n}{x^n+1};\frac{1}{n},1-\frac{1}{n}\right)+C.$$

Comment: The answer is also expressible in terms of the Lerch Transcendent $\Phi(x,1,a)$

Answer (score 47, accepted):

In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1354106/what-is-the-integration-of-int-1-x2n-1dx/1354485#1354485), I showed that that the indefinite integral of interest is given by

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\int\frac{1}{x^n+1}dx=-\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac12 x_{kr}\log(x^2-2x_{kr}x+1)-x_{ki}\arctan\left(\frac{x-x_{kr}}{x_{ki}}\right)\right)+C}
$$

for $n\ge 1$, where $x_{kr}$ and $x_{ki}$ can be written, respectively, as

$$x_{kr}=\cos \left(\frac{(2k-1)\pi}{n}\right)$$

$$x_{ki}=\sin \left(\frac{(2k-1)\pi}{n}\right)$$

---

For $n<0$, we simply write

$$\int \frac{1}{1+x^{-|n|}}\,dx=x-\int \frac{1}{1+x^{|n|}}\,dx$$

and use the aforementioned result with $n$ replaced with $|n|$.

Comment: Wow, that is quite beautiful.  Mind me asking if you can do anything for $n\in\mathbb Q$ or $\mathbb R$?

Comment: @SimpleArt Thank you for the nice comment!  Much appreciated.  Now, unfortunately, I don't know how to generalize this result to the case for non-integer values of $n$ without appealing to the hypergeometric function.  But that is unlikely the goal here.  -Mark

Comment: @marcocantarini Thanks Marco.  Much appreciative.

Comment: Would you be so kind as to look at $\displaystyle\int\frac{x^b}{1+x^a}dx$ for $a,b\in\mathbb N$?

Comment: @simpleart First, thank you so much for awarding this the 100 point bounty!  If you post the generalization, I'd be happy to have a look.  -Mark

Comment: You're welcome, you deserved it.  And it's already in under the $n\in\mathbb Q$ section.

Comment: Very nice! How in the world could I have missed this precious answer to this question? +1

Comment: @DonAntonio Thank you my friend!  And don't dismay.  There were several users that posted comments on the referenced answer who claimed that no closed form is possible.

Comment: You may be interested in [Evaluating $\int\frac{x^b}{1+x^a}~dx$ for $a,b\in\Bbb N$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2409312/272831)

Answer (score 11):

For positive integers $n$ you can write
$$ \dfrac{1}{1+x^n} = \sum_{\omega} \dfrac{r(\omega)}{x - \omega}$$
where the sum is over the $n$'th roots of $-1$ and $r(\omega)$ is the residue of $1/(1+x^n)$ at $x = \omega$, so that your integral is
$$ c + \sum_\omega r(\omega) \log(x - \omega)$$

You can also express the power series solution in terms of the Lerch Phi function:
$$ c + \dfrac{x}{n} {\rm LerchPhi}(-x^n,1,1/n) $$

Comment: Ah, interesting idea!  Basically equivalent to partial fraction decomposition.  Though it suggests I should use complex logarithms to write my $\arctan$.  If possible, keeping everything under real numbers is recommended.

Comment: Robert, [SEE THIS](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1354106/what-is-the-integration-of-int-1-x2n-1dx/1354485#1354485), in which I developed a closed-form solution.  ;-))

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different approach to Robert Israel's. Using $$\frac{1}{1+x}=1-x+x^2-x^3+x^4-\cdots,\tag{1}$$
where $|x|<1$ you can substitute $x^n$ for $x$ to obtain
$$\int\frac{1}{1+x^n}dx=\int 1-x^n+x^{2n}-x^{3n}+x^{4n}-\cdots dx$$

So we end up with

$$\int\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^kx^{kn}dx=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{x^{kn+1}}{kn+1}+c=\frac{x}{n} \Phi \left(-x^n,1,\frac{1}{n}\right)+c.$$
This actually works for $x,n\in\mathbb{R}$, but you'd have to prove that for $x$ since it does not follow from (1).

Comment: The series diverges when $|x|\ge 1$.