# Solving the integral $\int\frac{x^{\alpha}}{1+\psi x}\,\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I try to solve the following integral:

$$\int\frac{x^{\alpha}}{1+\psi x}\,\mathrm dx$$

What I try is to use the substitution method. I define $1+\psi x=u$ and this yields $\mathrm du=\psi\, \mathrm dx$

This gives me at final:

$$\int\frac{\left(u-1\right)^{\alpha}}{u\psi^{2}}\,\mathrm du$$

This one did not help me to solve the integral. What can I do to solve it?

Comment: you will need special functions for this one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $y=-bx$
\begin{align}
\int \frac{x^{a}}{1+bx} dx &= \left(\frac{1}{-b}\right)^{a+1} \int y^{a} (1-y)^{-1} dy \\
&= \left(\frac{1}{-b}\right)^{a+1} \mathrm{B}_{y}(a+1,0) \\
&= \left(\frac{1}{-b}\right)^{a+1} \mathrm{B}_{-bx}(a+1,0) \\
&= \left(\frac{1}{-b}\right)^{a+1} \frac{(-bx)^{a+1}}{a+1} {}_{2}\mathrm{F}_{1}(a+1,1;a+2;-bx) \\
&= \frac{x^{a+1}}{a+1} {}_{2}\mathrm{F}_{1}(a+1,1;a+2;-bx)
\end{align}

Note:
$$\mathrm{B}_{z}(x,y) = \int\limits_{0}^{z} t^{x-1} (1-t)^{y-1} dt 
= \frac{z^{x}}{x} {}_{2}\mathrm{F}_{1}(x,1-y;x+1;z)$$
the [incomplete beta function](http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.17.E1) and [Gauss's hypergeometric function](http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.17.E7) respectively.

Comment: Thanks for the incomplete beta function and gauss's hypergeometric function !

Comment: By the way, is it possible to use this method by using a definite integral (for example, summing between 0 and 1). Or is it necessary to use analytical continuation of gauss's hypergeometric function ?

Comment: do you mean $\int_{0}^{1}$ for the original integral?

Comment: yes exactly. I think it is possible to replace $z$ by some value that we should find, no ? as we use substitution, I think we should as well change for the upper bound. or is it just sufficient to replace $z$ by $1$ ?

Comment: you can plug in the values for x or if you start with $\int_{0}^{1}$ you can get the hypergeometric function directly by using the integral definition. either way, you obtain the same answer.

Comment: @poweierstrass I am sorry to bother you again. In the case of a definite integral, as you have written the formula above, is it possible to have a negative number for $z$ ? because in this case, the integral is between $0$ and a negative number.

Comment: i believe that it can via analytic continuation (see the links in my answer). however, you should check your solution numerically.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I checked it on Mathematica, it gives exact the same result. Nothing changes.