# $\int\frac{1}{x^6+1}dx$ Integrating a rational function, help with factoring the denominator

Tags: calculus, integration, polynomials, factoring

$$\int\frac{1}{x^6+1}\,dx$$

How to do this kind of integral, when one has a high degree polynomial in the denominator?

There is an idea in the book to add and subtract $x^2$ in the numerator, so one gets two integrals, but they are easy to do.

$$\int\frac{1}{x^6+1}\,dx = \int\frac{x^2+1}{x^6+1} \,dx - \int\frac{x^2}{x^6+1}\,dx$$

But how would I know that $x^6+1$ is divisible by $x^2+1$? Is there a method that doesn't rely on that division quirk?

Comment: Because $x^6+1=(x^2)^3+1^3$.... Because you have sum of cubes... $a^3+b^3=(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)$ So $x^6+1=(x^2+1)((x^2)^2-x^2+1)$

Comment: Another (perhaps more advanced way) would be to factor $x^6+1$ over the complex numbers, integrate the partial fractions with complex coefficients.

Comment: Related: [Evaluate $\int\frac1{1+x^n}dx$ for $n\in\mathbb R$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1999869/evaluate-int-frac11xndx-for-n-in-mathbb-r)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $x^3+1=(x+1)(x^2-x+1)$, $x^6+1=(x^2+1)(x^4-x^2+1)$. Therefore, your final sum is equal to$$\int\frac1{x^4-x^2+1}\,\mathrm dx-\int\frac{x^2}{x^6+1}\,\mathrm dx$$

Comment: You Sir are such a genius.

Comment: And what about 1/(x^4+1)?

Comment: @Shocky2 What about it? I made no mention to it and neither did you.

Comment: I ask if you could answer it too here, so I don't ask another question.

Comment: @Shocky2 Multiple questions at once are usually frowned upon, and answerers hold no obligation to answer new questions on old questions.

Comment: Excuse my unfamiliarness with the etiquette. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Next observe this.
$$x^4 - x^2 + 1 = x^4 + 2x^2 + 1 - 3x^2 = (x^2 + 1)^2 - \left(x\sqrt{3}\right)^2.$$
Factor this difference of squares to factor the quartic into two irreducible quadratics.  Then use a partial fractions expansion.

Answer (score 1):

$\dfrac{1}{x^6+1}=\dfrac{1}{(x-1) (x+1) \left(x^2-x+1\right) \left(x^2+x+1\right)}=$

$=
\dfrac{1}{6} \left(\dfrac{x}{x^2-x+1}-\dfrac{x}{x^2+x+1}-\dfrac{2}{x^2-x+1}-\dfrac{2}{x^2+x+1}+\dfrac{1}{x-1}-\dfrac{1}{x+1}\right)
$

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

note that $$\frac{1}{1+x^6}=1/3\, \left( {x}^{2}+1 \right) ^{-1}+1/3\,{\frac {-{x}^{2}+2}{{x}^{4}-
{x}^{2}+1}}
$$