# Integrate $\int \frac{a + x^n}{b + x^n}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I need to know whether this monster is integrable.

My fail attempts included: substituting $x^n$ by $z$ and also substituting for some smaller power of $n$, somehow using the fact that this is integrable for when n=1,[2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x2PLdgARyR8),[3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4wPQDmssR4Q). I searched a lot online, but could not managed to get an answer either.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: For this to be possible we need to find $$\int \frac{dx}{1+x^n}$$ which I highly doubt is possible. WolframAlpha gives you a closed form using hyper geometric functions if that’s what you’re interested in, however.

Comment: If $n$ is an integer, then the integrand is a rational function, which are always integrable by partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comments! @DavidH yes, $n$ is assumed to be an integer, thank you. Do you know however some general solution for it? Or we can just state a closed form solution exists?

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1999869/695196) might be useful.

Comment: You can always split the integral, into $\int \frac{adx}{b+x^n} +\int\frac{dx}{\frac{b}{x^n}+1}$. Suppose $b$ is a value such that an $n$-th root can exist, you can do the substitutions $x=\frac{u}{b^{1/n}}$ for the first integral and $ x = \frac{b^{1/n}}{u}$ for the second integral. This should turn it into $\frac{a}{b^{1+1/n}}\int\frac{du}{1+u^n} - \int \frac{du}{u^2(1+u^2)}$. Where you can use pfd like DavidH suggested and hypergeometric functions like intellect4 suggested.

Comment: @Sarah A general solution for arbitrary $n$ requires we do two things: 1) find a general formula for the roots of the denominator, and 2) a general formula for the p.f.d. coefficients. The first part is easy since they’re just roots of unity. The second part is much hairier. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition#Residue_method

Comment: The result for the hypergeometric function is easy to transform into an lerch transcendent as seen in a linked answer which usually simplifies down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$I=\int \frac{a + x^n}{b + x^n}dx=\int \frac{b+(a-b) + x^n}{b + x^n}dx=\int dx+(a-b)\int \frac{ dx  }{b + x^n}$$
Let $x=y \,b^{\frac{1}{n}}$
$$I=x + (a-b)\, b^{\frac{1}{n}-1}\int \frac {dy}{1+y^n}$$ For the remaining integral, you could use partial fraction decompositions with the roots of unity (not the most pleasant) or use the gaussian [hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function)
$$\int \frac {dy}{1+y^n}=y \, _2F_1\left(1,\frac{1}{n};\frac{n+1}{n};-y^n\right)$$ where $n$ can be any number